# How to give write option in mail attachments and notification when mail send in nodejs using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, email-attachments, nodemailer

I am sending mail with pdf and word file attachments using nodemailer in nodejs.

I want to edit the document and give notification when mail received to clients.

I searched but I did not get anything regarding this. How can I give the edit options and notification when they receive mail from us?.

when I sent mail to the receiver, I can send the attachment, however, I'm not able to edit that attachment document and notification also.

I spent one day still I didn't get anything properly regarding edit options in attachments.

Someone help me, please.

Comment: You can't edit a PDF file. However, Gmail will automatically add an edit option to word files.  [Please see this link](https://www.theverge.com/2014/12/2/7324401/gmail-now-lets-you-edit-microsoft-office-documents-from-your-inbox)

Comment: ok,how to enable notification bell in mail when i sent a mail to client?

Comment: Do you want to show the notification bell inside your mail template?

Comment: yes,Inside mail template

Comment: You can include that bell icon in your HTML code for the email template.

Comment: In gmail when i sent mail to another persons that time ,he will get new mail in inbox as same as notification .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180184/discussion-between-sukanya-purushothaman-and-uma-raja).